# Python - How to to use subplot for with different member functions of a class

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I would like to use the subplot function of matplotlib with different member functions of a class. However I do not seem to get all plots in one window.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm, gaussian_kde
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import ceil

class cl():
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = np.array(x)
        self.mean = np.nanmean(x)
        self.std = np.nanstd(x)
    def pit(self):
         y = norm.cdf((self.x-self.mean)/self.std)
         kernel = gaussian_kde(y)
         title= r'$\mathrm{Histogram\ of\ pit:}$'
         self.plot(kernel.resample(10000).T, title)

    def plotx(self):
        title=r'$\mathrm{Histogram\ of\ x:}$'
        self.plot(self.x, title)

    def plot(self, x, title):

        nbins = ceil(2*len(x)**(1.0/3.0)) 
        n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, nbins, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)
        plt.xlabel('X')
        plt.ylabel('Probability')
        plt.title(title)
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.show()

test=cl(np.random.randn(100000))
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
test.plotx()
plt.subplot(212)
test.pit()
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what exactly do you want the output to look like ? If you want to have all plots in one graph why are you using different subplots?

Comment: I would like to have one figure with two subplots, i.e. two graphs in one window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the plt.show() routine in your class blocks the program at runtime until you close the plotwindow. Therefore you should use the `plt.draw()` command in your class and the plt.show() command once at the end of your program. i.e.:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm, gaussian_kde
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import ceil

class cl():
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = np.array(x)
        self.mean = np.nanmean(x)
        self.std = np.nanstd(x)
    def pit(self):
         y = norm.cdf((self.x-self.mean)/self.std)
         kernel = gaussian_kde(y)
         title= r'$\mathrm{Histogram\ of\ pit:}$'
         self.plot(kernel.resample(10000).T, title)

    def plotx(self):
        title=r'$\mathrm{Histogram\ of\ x:}$'
        self.plot(self.x, title)

    def plot(self, x, title):

        nbins = ceil(2*len(x)**(1.0/3.0))
        n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, nbins, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)
        plt.xlabel('X')
        plt.ylabel('Probability')
        plt.title(title)
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.draw()

test=cl(np.random.randn(100000))
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
test.plotx()
plt.subplot(212)
test.pit()

plt.show()
```